# createWindowContext failed! Too many unused window contexts

Tags: android

I received a crash report about this earlier today.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: createWindowContext failed! 
Too many unused window contexts. Please see Context createWindowContext documentation for detail.
```

Looking at the documentation for `Context#createWindowContext`, it mentions:

> Creating a window context is an expensive operation. Misuse of this
> API may lead to a huge performance drop. The best practice is to use
> the same window context when possible. An approach is to create one
> window context with specific window type and display and use it
> everywhere it's needed.

Searching for this crash, I cant find **anything** though. Their suggestion makes perfect sense, but Im not sure how I should apply it to my use-case.

**My use-case:** A service is started when the app is backgrounded. The service displays an overlay that uses a context from `createWindowContext`. If you open/close the app multiple times over a short period of time, this issue comes up due to `createWindowContext` being called everytime the service is started.

The only thing that comes to mind is storing the created windowContext in the companion object of the service. Ive tested this briefly and it *works*, but am I shooting myself in the foot by doing it? **Are there any other, better solutions to this?** Ive considered storing the windowContext (in the companion object) using a WeakReference as well.

For reference, here is the code that Im using to create the windowContext. This happens in my `service:onCreate` and is then passed to a `ComposeView` which is added to the window using `WindowManager.addView(...)`.

```
    private fun Context.displayContext(): Context {
        val manager = getSystemService(DISPLAY_SERVICE) as DisplayManager
        val display = manager.getDisplay(DEFAULT_DISPLAY)
        return createDisplayContext(display)
    }

    private fun Context.windowContext(): Context {
        return if (SDK_INT >= R) {
            createWindowContext(
                WindowType,
                null,
            )
        } else {
            this
        }
    }
```

Comment: hey did you ever figure out the issue?

Comment: The solution I mentioned has worked flawlessly!